# How not to show hand cursor on links in web browser?

Tags: c#

In web browser of Visual C#, if the user moves the cursor on to the link, the cursor would be changed into a hand automatically.. I want to change this.. I want to make my program not to show hand if user moves the cursor on to a link in the web browser of my program.. I checked all the web browser properties in visual C# and I couldn't find any settings to do it.. Is it possible or not ?

If it is, how can I do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please revise your tags. This question does not seem to be related to Visual Studio, or any of its editions or versions. Instead, list the UI toolkit you are using, that the web browser control you are referring to is a part of (and ideally, also link to that control - e.g. to its MSDN docs page - in your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by injecting a CSS rule into the browser control.

What you want to do is add the style/css property `cursor:default`

You can do this by injecting a style element into the head section:

```
HtmlElement headTag = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement styleEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("style");
IHTMLStyleElement element = (IHTMLStyleElement)styleEl.DomElement;
IHTMLStyleSheetElement styleSheet = element.styleSheet;
styleSheet.cssText = @"a { cursor: default }";
head.AppendChild(styleEl);
```

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be a comment.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without injecting a CSS rule ?

Comment: Not as far as I know, the control is essentially a browser in a window so once you move the mouse into it, the behaviour is delegated to the control. You could possibly override the behaviour but I suspect this would be virtually impossible.

Comment: And there is a line of code 

"HtmlElement headTag = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];"

But the content of my browser doesnt contain a head tag.. Would this be work with it ?

Comment: If your document doesn't contain a head tag you should create one, so if headTag is null then consider getting the `html` tag instead and adding one. However you could just add the style tag anyway, it will work with most browsers although it's a bad practice, but then so is not having a head tag (it is permitted but a bad idea)

Comment: It probably should be `@"a { cursor: default !important}";` or it might not stick if the HTML page style has `!important` cursor setting on its own